# i made right set, but there is key error in gurobipy

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I made linear program model in gurobipy like this

```
def cal_gl_1():
    m = gp.Model('Inventory')
    s=['AUC','ADU','CF','LT']  #AUC: average unit cost, ADU: annual dollar usage, CF: critical factor, LT: lead time
    item_number=list(range(1,11))
    def cal_s_1():
        s_auc=[71.21, 58.45, 40.82, 19.86, 86.50, 71.2, 78.4, 51.68, 14.66, 72]   
        list_key = [('AUC',1),('AUC',2),('AUC',3),('AUC',4),('AUC',5),('AUC',6),('AUC',7),
        ('AUC',8),('AUC',9),('AUC',10)]
        auc=dict(zip(list_key,s_auc))
        return auc
    Lj = m.addVars(item_number,lb=0, name ="lamda" )
    ACU=cal_s_1()
    for r in s[0]:
       m.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(Lj[j]*ACU[r,j])>=ACU[r,j] for j in item_number)

       obj=(Lj[j].sum(j,'*') for j in item_number)
       m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)
       m.optimize()
       data_all.append(m.objVal)
    return data_all
```

However there is keyerror.

```
KeyError: ('A', 1)
```

I think there right key ('AUC',1)...('AUC',10). I don't know which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
for r in s[0]:
```

Try:

```
for r in s:
```

Else `r` will be `['A', 'U', 'C']` and not `['AUC','ADU','CF','LT']`.

But maybe you want to constraints only for `'AUC'`. In this case, use:

```
for r in ['AUC']:
```

or `r = 'AUC'` without loop.